# Parse: Send updates to clients without notification

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I´m adding a chat function to my Parse-app and I´m pretty stuck on how to update the other devices when a user sends a message.

Is push notification the only way to let the other devices know that they should update their chat-view? I don´t really want them to receive notifications when not using the application.

I´m pretty green at Parse and if I misunderstood something, please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use a silent push notification. Parse lets you specify the push JSON payload. If you put in an empty alert as well as a content-available: 1 in the push payload, it will send a silent push. Your app will be notified of the push but the user will not see a message. iOS will then give your app the chance to refresh your data. Your JSON will look something like this:

{
  "alert" : ""
  "content-available" : 1
}

From Apple's docs:
The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property. The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a “silent” notification. When a silent notification arrives, iOS wakes up your app in the background so that you can get new data from your server or do background information processing. Users aren’t told about the new or changed information that results from a silent notification, but they can find out about it the next time they open your app.

You can find more info here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the notifications when the app is running, then you can use polling. It isn't as efficient as push notifications but it might be better suited for your app. You would just need to query for anything since your last check.

This can be done using a date-time or for bonus points try setting up a shared counter with `increment()` in cloud code, calling that in before-save and attaching that value to each record so they all have a unique number so you just query for any records > last-number-you-got.